# How i show f is integrable and calculate its integral.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $a < b$ and $f\colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a step function, that is, there exist a partition
$$P = (a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b)$$ and numbers $c_1,c_2,\ldots, c_n$, such that for all
$j = 1,\ldots,n, f(x) = c_j$ for all $x \in (x_{j-1}, x_j ]$. How do I show $f$ is integrable and calculate its integral?

Comment: Hint : $f$ is a staged function.

Comment: Please explain what you've tried and how this problem arises in your studies.  In particular, are you asking about Riemann integrability or Lebesgue integrability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We know that every bounded monotonic function is integrable, and furthermore that every bounded piecewise monotonic function is integrable by the additive property of integrals with respect to the integrand, over an interval. Since $f$ is a step function, it is a bounded piecewise monotonic function, and consequently integrable over $[a,b]$. To compute the value of $\int_a^b f(x)~dx$, we recall that the integral from $a$ to $b$ of a constant function $g(x) = c$ is $c(b - a)$ and apply the additive property of integrals to obtain $\int_a^b f(x)~dx = \int_{x_0}^{x + 1} f(x)~dx + \ldots + \int_{x_{n - 1}}^{x_n} f(x)~dx$, where $P = \{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)$ is constant on each open subinterval of $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that for any refinement of $P$ the upper and lower partial sums are not altered. Moreover, that $L(f,P')=U(f,P')$ for any refinement $P'$ of $P$.